# How to go back on two view states (something like $window.history.go(-2))?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In Ionic I can go back just using:

```
var backView = $ionicViewService.getBackView();
backView && backView.go();
```

The question is how to go to the view before backView? Something like:

```
var backBackView = $ionicViewService.getView(-2);
backBackView && backBackView.go();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some experiments I ended with next solution:

```
var backView = $scope.$viewHistory.views[$scope.$viewHistory.backView.backViewId];
$scope.$viewHistory.forcedNav = {
    viewId:     backView.viewId,
    navAction: 'moveBack',
    navDirection: 'back'
};
backView && backView.go();
```

It looks bad for me, but successfully resolves the problem. I hope this will help to someone.

**Update**: Now you could actually call

```
$ionicHistory.goBack(-2);
```

which is described in [ionic's documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/).

Comment: Saved my life man. Back button implementation was not working when I put nav bars in each view

Comment: @islahul I'm glad that helped to someone)

Comment: Thanks to @Tiesselune for the [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8150102)

Comment: $ionicHistory.goBack(-2) worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I've found the following to be the quickest way to go backwards when deep in a view stack:

```
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```

I believe you can call that multiple times in a loop to keep going back in the view history.  Of course, you have to inject $ionicHistory in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

This is now available in nightlies using `$ionicGoBack(amount)` https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/63a0834d63eb87b86238fccde4bf4e77f3540085